# Defining bounding box within Add WFS Layer dialog of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wfs

I use QGIS 1.8 under WIN XP in Standalone Installer Version. I need to limit the extent of the data to be downloaded via WFS because of the large amount of data in the requested layer. In older/different versions of QGIS there used to be a check box within the Add WFS layer dialog to limit the WFS download to the actual view. In my version of QGIS it is missing. What is the best way to set a bounding box for WFS download or how can I get above mentioned check box?

Comment: Not sure.. but you can restrict those settings in xml. Please check following link http://www.ogcnetwork.net/wfstutorial

Comment: This issue is described here http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4604 and is still opened.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that calls for Ordnance Survey OpenData Vectors:

```
http://www.osmgb.org.uk/ogc/wfs-vmd?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=OS-VMD:road&SRSNAME=EPSG:27700&BBOX=447901.707808,337571.014355,453015.418400,341833.260141
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this hint, here is how I´ve done it: I started downloading the WFS content via add WFS layer dialog and canceld the action. QGIS will add the layer anyway, with zero objects. In properties menu for this layer I copied the getFeature address line, added above mentioned &BBOX=.... extension and went back to the Add WFS layer menu. There I created a new WFS source and pasted the extended GetFeature command instead of the GetProperties address, hit the Add button and ... done.

Answer (score 0):

It is in Project Settings in the OWS tab

Comment: Thank you, but as I understand the OWS settings define boundaries when QGIS is employed as server. I have problems downloading WFS from an external server...

Comment: The question is about using QGIS as a WFS client.